# is "this" as a param a reference?

Tags: c#, reference, xna

I am developing a level editor in Xna and my question is that when you call a method using "this" as a param is the param a reference or a value?

Ex:

```
class A_Class
{
    private B_Class bClass;

    public void aMethod()
    {
        bClass.bMethod(this);
    }
}

class B_Class
{
    public void bMethod(A_Class aClass)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: C# passes a reference by default.

Comment: Depends on whether `this` is a class or a struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a reference to the calling A_Class object, because classes are reference-type.
More specifically, as noted in other questions on reference/value, it is passing a value, and that value is a reference to the calling A_Class object.

If rather than A_Class, it was A_Struct, `this` would be passed by value, as Structs are value-type.

Comment: Wouldn't it pass by value if calling from within a struct, ie `this` is actually a value type?

Comment: True. The OP specified it as a class, but it's good to have the information for both there.

Comment: The OP was merely giving an example for the question. It is possible that he is facing the situation with a struct rather than a class. I would edit the answer to be full and more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Passing 'this' or any object for that matter, will be pass a value equal to the reference.

Comment: It passes **a** reference, but it does not pass it **by** reference.

Comment: It passes the value of the reference.

Comment: Ok fixed, even though the difference is pretty much never relevant in C# =P.

Answer (score -1):

By default, parameters are passed **by VALUE**. If the param is a reference type, the VALUE is the reference to the real data. And if the param is a value type, the VALUE is the data the value type holds. In your code, `A_Class` is a reference type, so passing `this` as param actually passes the VALUE of the `A_Class` object, and it is the reference to the real data.

You can use `ref` keywords to make them passed **by reference**.

See [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.